# Why is there an error called Fatal error: Cannot declare class FPDF, because the name is already in use? How to fix this?

Tags: php, xampp, fpdf

I am currently working with FPDF and PHP.
I use the offical files:

```
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\rotation.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\ex.php');
```

so I suspect, that there might be some complications because I use so many files which include the class FPDF.

The Error itself occures on Line 10 of the official FPDF document:

```
class FPDF {
```

How do i fix this? I read online that I have to write not required('fpdf.php'), instead I should write, for example, require_once('fpdf.php');

But this didn't work for me here.

Comment: `FPDF` is declared as a class in `fpdf.php`. You're probably trying to declare another class `FPDF` somewhere, so change your class name

Comment: The only other script which uses the FPDF Class is "class PDF_Rotate extends FPDF" - do I change the name of the original FPDF.php or the name in the PDF_Rotate class?

Comment: Neither. Those stay as-is. Do you have a class that's extending `PDF_Rotate`?

Comment: Yes I have
Its the class: class PDF extends PDF_Rotate

Now that I go through it, I see it calls FPDF one time in line 23 with:

"$pdf=new PDF();"

Do I need to change the name of this PDF?

Comment: Make sure only 1 file is requiring `fpdf.php`, or all instances use `require_once`

Comment: Every file which uses the fpdf.php has is through require_once thats why I am so confused about the error

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you missed one. Try starting again with references to it, and build up your code again until you get the error (or you don't get it, if you replaced them all correctly)